# ¿Como escribir un javascript en wordpress 4.6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Buenas tardes,como puedo meter un pequeño codigo en javascript y como deberia de ir en una sola pagina de wordpress.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var es_safari = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
    var mediaquery = window.matchMedia("(max-media: 1920px)") ;

        if (es_safari && ) {
            if (mediaquery) {
                var o = document.getElementById('box-context-a1');
                o.style.left = '38.200%';               
                var o2 = document.getElementById('box-context-a2');
                o2.style.left = '38.200%';              
                var o3 = document.getElementById('box-context-a3');
                o3.style.left = '38.200%';
                var o4 = document.getElementById('box-context-b1');
                o4.style.left = '38.200%';
                var o5 = document.getElementById('box-context-b2');
                o5.style.right = '38.200%';
                var o6 = document.getElementById('box-context-c1');
                o6.style.right = '38.200%';
                var o7 = document.getElementById('box-context-c2');
                o7.style.right = '38.200%';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba uno de estos 3, a ver si con tu  versión de Wordpress te entra:

[1. Css-Javascript-Toolbox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/css-javascript-toolbox/)

[2. Simple Custom Css](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/)

También, y si no quieres usar plugins, puedes insertarlo directamente sobre el post/página que quieras, poniendo el editor en la vista de **texto** e insertando el siguiente código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // ...
    alert("tu código javascript aquí");
    // ...
</script>
```

Comment: La cosa es que por usar una plantilla de wordpress no encuentro ni siquiera el nombre de la pagina dentro del directorio de el cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Una de las maneras mas sencillas es usar este plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/scripts-n-styles/ puedes meter un codigo de jquery o js en la pagina o post que desees. Una vez instalado vas a la pagina en cuestión y abajo del contenido de la pagina te habrá insertado un cajetin donde puedes insertar JS.

Un saludo

Comment: tengo la version 4.6.6 y me dice que es incompatible no habra problema alguno?

Comment: dudo mucho que lo haya, si ves algún problema desinstalalo. De todos modos xq no actualizas el wordpress???

Comment: por la razon de que me pueda presentar fallas en mi plantilla!

Comment: mas fallas vas a tener si vas a dejar el wordpress por siempre desactualizado, prepara un backup de todo y prueba a actualizar, mi recomendación y siempre buscar plantillas que se actualizen si no luego pasan estas cosas.

Comment: bueno la verdad muchas gracias sinceramente me has ayudado con el plugin, solo que el cliente no quiere actualizar el wordpress!